# PHP str_replace with array() not working ? (have example)

Tags: php, str-replace

[code]

```
echo str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', "(test) i'm test"); exit;
```

[run]

```
(test) i'm test
```

I want to remove brackets from this text, but it not working?

Comment: Nope, it works: https://3v4l.org/NFG0c

Comment: @Nattapat what u get in output!! its working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code removes parentheses `(`, `)` from the following string:

`(test) i'm test"`

```
$string = "(test) i'm test";
echo str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $string);
```

The results after using the [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function:

`test i'm test"`

Comment: It would be good if you will add a short explanation in your answer. It will help OP and others to understand about the solution.

Comment: Sure. I will add it